# Table reading last variable

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, session-variables

All I am trying to do is put a SESSION variable into a DoNav function in a table. At the moment the DoNav function is reading the last SESSION variable because it reads all the script and reads the last variable (overwrites).

It won't read the variable and then for it to go to the next page immediately without corrupting the SESSION variable from other table rows below. I have tried these below to no effect.

```
    <tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php? <?php $_SESSION['RID']=1;?> ')";>
    <tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php?')"; <?php $_SESSION['RID']=1;?>> 
    <tr onclick=<?php $_SESSION['RID']=1;?>; "DoNav('http://newpage.php?')";>
```

I just need the correct code for the tr line to make the variable write once.

Comment: Hi there. I see you are getting a baptism of fire on your most recent question - that happens here sometimes! A few useful tips to make your questions a bit better: (1) make them as succinct as possible. Resist the temptation to add "please help", "I've worked on this for ages", signatures, thanks in advance, "I'm about to throw the laptop out the window" etc. (2) Instead, demonstrate what you have tried. Ask for help on a specific problem, but not "I need the code for this" - even if it is not the case, that makes it look like you want someone to do your work for you.

Comment: (3) If you are having trouble describing what you presently have, consider uploading your script to a free PHP host, and linking to it here (whilst also adding code here, to prevent link rot). (4) Don't ask essentially the same question many times, as that may attract extra close votes. Final note: I know asking for advice on the web may initially appear onerous to beginners, especially here - we try to tread a fine line between being helpful and requiring prior effort, and it's a difficult balance `:)`. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the `DoNav` function is or where it comes from, but if you're just trying to get the `$_SESSION['RID']` to be outputted as text, you should just be able to change this:

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php? <?php $_SESSION['RID']=1;?> ')";>
```

to this:

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php?<?php print $_SESSION['RID']; ?>')";>
```

or better yet (for debugging / avoiding errors):

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php?<?php print isset($_SESSION['RID']) ? $_SESSION['RID'] : 'NOSESSION'; ?>')";>
```

... where `NOSESSION` will be displayed in case `$_SESSION['RID']` is not set (change it to whatever you want obviously... Just there to help you figure out where the problem is).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @jerdiggity.... I have a table and each row is clickable to send it to a new page, (DoNav) function. What I need is for a variable to be transferred to the new page (id of that row). I was going to use a session variable. Problem is, that the last last rows variable is transferred.... i.e. If I have 30 rows and I click on the first row.... the id of row 30 is transferred. The variable is overwritten. Each row has a DoNav(href reference to the new page). I need a code to send a php variable (id) with the row that is clicked. Cheers